# RFID on humans, is RFID the right method?

Tags: rfid

Me and my friends have thought of a few RFID solutions. One of them involve creating RFID tracking system to detect sailors out in the sea within 5km via a tablet or pc. Can this be done? 
`Reason because sailors dont wear lifejackets. Which we are thinking of creating wristbands. However we do not know if this is the right way to do it because of its range and radiation.`
Setting up a reader on a buoy could be done.

Answer (score 3):

No, it can't be done. RFIDs work in the "near field", which is the area around an antenna where the transmitter can sense changes in signal absorption.

Low frequency RFID (125 kHz) works at distances in the centimeter range. High frequency RFID (13 MHz) is used up to a couple of meters. There's no way a transmitter can detect a tag at kilometers of distance.

**edit in reply to PeterJ's comment**
RFID is the name of a technology where receiver tags actively load the RF signal (the carrier), and that load is detected by the transmitter. By pulsing the load a signal is sent to the transmitter.
There are lots of RF data transmitter-receivers which can reach up to tens of kilometers, but they're not RFID.

**better solution**
A better solution would be an ordinary transmitter equipped with GPS receiver, which broadcasts an SOS (I think there's an RF band reserved for this) including GPS coordinates.

Comment: Some active tags like 433MHz can have a range more like 100 meters. Plus RFID is a pretty broad term, for example while I can't think of anything off-the-shelf if I made a 10W VHF identification system I can't see a reason I couldn't describe it as long-range RFID.

Comment: Thanks for the info. Im looking for something that works like a fish radar, so i can locate my sailors. Is there other ways?

Comment: @PeterJ I added to the answer.

Answer (score 2):

Classic RFID - passive tags - won't work in this role because of range limitations.

Plus the ID part - identification - is unnecessary. If a sailor is lost at sea, SAR teams really don't need to identify him - they just need to find him, whoever he is! So an active beacon that can be homed onto is more useful. And for that purpose, LF (125kHz) would be an interesting choice : good range with little power, and predominantly magnetic coupling (ferrite rod antenna). Propagating E fields from salt-soaked antennae is famously problematic.

But it would be better to stick to existing bands for compatibility with existing locator systems ( 121 MHz, or 406MHz satellite readable)

Useful search terms : PLB, EPIRB.

EDIT : where these beacons are used over much longer range, e.g. satellite detection, and SAR is centrally coordinated (because the UK's MCA controversially closed most of their incident control centres last year) the beacons do have identification, to help someone hundreds of miles away distinguish a real incident from a normal wet night on a fishing boat.